# Three Dimension Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a master table with the following structure in excel :
[image]

How can I convert it as shown in the second picture by using the vlookup function? (function in yellow cells).
Three keys involved now: Daytime, User and Data Type (ADP_ERQ, ADP_SO)

Note: Column headers (Daytime, User, ADP_ERQ, ADP_SO) in the second picture are fixed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in C17 then fill right and down.

```
=INDEX($A$3:$Z$12, MATCH($A17, $A$3:$A$12, 0), AGGREGATE(15, 7, (COLUMN(1:1)+MATCH($B17, $1:$1, 0)-2)/($2:$2=C$16), 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Also thought about using index and match at first. It does make it more responsive, and it has the benefit of having only one formula. Although I like my solution for its simplicity.

Comment: I was thinking (after cursing the op for making me retype the data) that there may actually be more than two users. Providing that each user has the same number of *adp_xx*'s, this should provide flexibility for expansion.

Comment: Thanks all!! Sorry for making you to retype the data :( But i am not really understand about the second half of the function : **AGGREGATE(15, 7, (COLUMN(1:1)+MATCH($B17, $1:$1, 0)-2)/($2:$2=C$16), 1)**
Understand that we are using the SMALL function, but not sure what is the purpose of COLUMN(1:1), i tried it always return 1, can we just make it as fix number ?

Comment: column(1:1) is actually an array of all column numbers.

Answer (score 1):

For cell C17: `IF(B17="USER_A",VLookup(A17,A3:C12,2,0),VLookup(A17,A3:E12,4,0))`

For cell D17: `IF(B17="USER_A",VLookup(A17,A3:C12,3,0),VLookup(A17,A3:E12,5,0))`

In this formula replace `A3:C12` and `A3:E12` with your appropriate table range, then drag these down.